# Receber e Enviar JSON C#

Tags: php, c#, json

Em uma aplicação local "WindowsForm" em C#, preciso enviar e receber dados via JSON para uma página PHP , existe alguma função pré-definida  para isso ?

Comment: Jovem, explique melhor o que deseja fazer. Aliás, o que tag PHP faz nessa pergunta?

Comment: Pra onde eu preciso enviar e receber JSON é uma página em PHP

Comment: Tá, e o que você está fazendo em C#? É uma página web? Um app console? Você precisa [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes, senão sua publicação pode ser fechada por estar pouco clara...

Comment: Você sabe o básico sobre isso? Dá uma lida nos primeiros resultados para você ter uma noção do que está fazendo: https://goo.gl/sq9Az8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Praticamente você precisa de algumas declarações para que seu WebServices funcione.

> [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

Especifica o verbo HTTP é usado para chamar um método e o formato da resposta. Essa classe não pode ser herdada. [Detalhes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

> JavaScriptSerializer

Json.NET deve ser usado de serialização e desserialização. Fornece a funcionalidade de serialização e desserialização para aplicativos que usam AJAX. [Detalhes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

> writeJsonData

E um método que monte seu JSON (response), como exemplo: writeJsonData

Vejas detalhes de um [Serviços Web XML a partir do Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/scf355x6(v=vs.90).aspx) 
e  [Vincular a um Web Service usando o BindingSource do Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ff855828(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod()]
public void DadosUsuario(String IdUsuario, String Chave)
{
    using (var DBCtx = new WdbContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var Usuario = DBCtx.tb_Usuarios.FirstOrDefault();
            if (Usuario != null)
                RetornarJson(DBCtx, Usuario);  
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
        }
    }
}

private void RetornarJson(WdbContext DBCtx, tb_Usuarios Usu)
{
    string RespJson = String.Empty;

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    RespJson = js.Serialize(Usu);
    writeJsonData(RespJson);            
}

protected void writeJsonData(string s)
{
    HttpContext context = this.Context;
    HttpResponse response = context.Response;
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    byte[] b = response.ContentEncoding.GetBytes(s);
    response.AddHeader("Content-Length", b.Length.ToString());
    response.BinaryWrite(b);
    try
    {
        this.Context.Response.Flush();
        this.Context.Response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```